# When are $\mathfrak O_K/\mathfrak p^m$ and $\mathbb Z/p^m\mathbb Z$ isomorphic as $\mathbb Z$ modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given an algebraic field $K$ and denote by $\mathfrak O_K$ its ring of integers. Suppose that $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal and $p$ is a prime contained in $\mathfrak p$. Under what conditions of $\mathfrak p$ can $\mathfrak O_K/\mathfrak p^m$ be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p^m\mathbb Z$ as $\mathbb Z$-modules?

Note that if they are isomorphic, then the number of elements in $\mathfrak O_K/\mathfrak p^m$ must be $p^m$ and therefore the norm of $\mathfrak p$ must be $p$. Is this condition also sufficient? Or what is the sufficient condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is not sufficient. Let $e$ and $f$ denote the ramification and inertial degrees of $\mathfrak{p}/p$. The norm homomorphism satisfies $N(\mathfrak{p}) = p^f$, so the condition that $N(\mathfrak{p}) = p$ is equivalent to the condition $f = 1$. This implies that $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic as fields (and hence $\mathbb{Z}$-modules), so your condition does work for $m = 1$.

However, for larger $m$, you need to add an addition hypothesis. Indeed, the smallest power of $p$ in $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^m$ is equal to $p^t$ where $t = \lceil \frac{m}{e} \rceil$. Assuming $f = 1$, we know that $|\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^m| = p^m$, so the $\mathbb{Z}$-module isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^m \equiv \mathbb{Z}/p^m$ holds iff the smallest power of $p$ in $\mathfrak{p}^m$ to be $p^m$. It is easy to check that this is true iff $m = 1$ or $e = 1$.